# LINQ, Search sql server table column with contain function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

In my Asp.Net Mvc 5 application, I want to search via LINQ query expression, all the SKUs from a SQL Server 2012 table (tbl(sku nvarchar(100))) which contain 'P' and the count of all 'P's should be equal to '5'. 
Note: The character e.g 'P' and the count '5' are variables.

I have tried the following so far:

```
var skus = productiondata.Where(x => x.OrderItemSKU.Contains('P'));
```

Comment: what have you try so far?

Comment: I have edited the question to work done so far @teovankot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can easily be done at the client side, but I guess that's not the point. To make it happen in the EF db query, you can use something like this

```
char ch = 'P';
int count = 5;

var s = ch.ToString(); // important
var skus = productiondata
    .Where(x => x.OrderItemSKU.Length - x.OrderItemSKU.Replace(s, "").Length == count);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your code it should be:

```
var skus = productiondata.Where(x => x.OrderItemSKU.Count(y => y == 'p') == 5);
```

Comment: following exception is being thrown DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType. :(